# Forms and buttons

Tags: html, forms

I would like to have some guidance on how to make good forms with submit buttons that look flat but not like the default ones that are done when using html. I want the submit buttons like those found on this website.

Answer (score 0):

You should try applying CSS to your submit buttons like follow:

```
<head>
.......
your html code
.....
<style>
.pass {
   width: 105px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 2px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #065fba;
   background: #f4f5f8;
   font-size: 11px;
   border: #e2e2e2 1px solid;
 }
</style>
</head>
.......
your html code
.....
<input trpe="submit" class="pass" value="Submit" />
......
...
.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The css use for the 'Post Your Answer' button on this website is (more or less):

```
input[type="submit"] {
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
```

For cross-browser compatibility you'll need to add a class to your `<input type="submit" />` as the CSS `[type=""]` attribute isn't recognised in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how *any* element has been styled on any examples you like the look of, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or its equivalents for other browsers, which will show you the CSS applicable to a selected element.

In Stack Overflow's case, it's this, with the buttons being wrapped with a `<div class="form-submit">`:

```
.form-submit input {
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```